# trying to create a single file in eclipse for Java , but two getting created at different file hierarchy

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to create a new class in Eclipse under a project folder.

File Structure:

Intro To Java

-Chap2

```
-default package

  -File 1
  -File 2
  -File 3
-File 3
```

Initially I could create single files by adding new class. But when I am creating a new class now , 2 file get created - one under default and one outside default. Even though there are no errors shown, it would be nice if somebody can explain why this is happening and how to resolve it.

Comment: its about where you give right click.

Comment: I am doing the right click on the default package, I just tried the right click on the chap2 folder also , both create the same class file under default package and File 3. has it got something to do with selecting fields under the "New Java Class"

Comment: Does you java project have a src folder with the default package under it, or is the java project the root of your classpath?

Comment: @paul , thanks for the insight. I changed the path name of the file.   just added a "/" at the end of default path and that solved the issues.

Comment: @paul , the problem still persists.

Comment: the issue is more specific to eclipse as in my file system i dint see two files, only one exists.

Comment: You really should provide a screenshot.  Or more than one.

Comment: And does your java project have a `src` folder, or does the source start at the root of the project?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too (I don't know the exact reason why?)
But, re-creating the file or re-starting Eclipse didn't help me.
But when I restarted the laptop, the second file was gone.